# Is it still possible to scrape data from public facebook pages?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-media

I want to scrape comments from a public facebook page (news network) through the facebook graph api.
However it says i need to create a app to do this.

After a bit of research I found out that facebook prohibits web scraping since the cambridge analytica scandal.

Is there still a legal way to scrape data from facebook? 
Does somebody here have experience he/she can share?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that violates their terms of service. Since you must log in to see their web site, I'm guessing your account would get suspended.

Answer (score 4):

I dont know about the legality of scraping facebook,
but you can use a library called [facebook_scraper](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/)

for instance:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

for post in get_posts(name_of_your_public_group, pages=10):
    print(post['text'],'\n')
```

Note: working only for public pages

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but you have to create an App and apply for Page Public Content Access: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

...after that, you can get the feed of a public Page with the `/page-id/feed` endpoint, with an App Access Token.